# Is there any API to get metadata schema for Google Drive rest API

Tags: google-drive-api

On Google Drive documentation I could see schema for individual resources like File,Permissions etc but no where mentioned about API for meat data of all resources.

Comment: What like you want to see information about the API itself like what methods it supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Discovery Service API](https://developers.google.com/discovery/) is an interesting if little known API it gives you all the information you could ever need about Google APIs.

If you take the following command and place it in a web browser you will see everything you could ever want to know about the Google Drive API v3.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest
```